# Photo, when zoomed to actual size look unsharp, "dotted" and noisy

Tags: dslr, troubleshooting, timelapse, panasonic-lumix

I am video-maker. And I tried to make timelapse video, which mean that I took several thousands of photos to glue them into video. Every photo look something like this:
[image: Full image]

The idea was to zoom parts of the photos to actual size, to get rid of ceiling and other areas, where nothing happens. However, when I zoom photo to actual size, it looks like this:
[image]
Unsharp and somekind of "dotted". With noise.

I don't have much experience in still photography, and I don't know what is the name of that problem to google it. Can someone explain, what I am doing wrong, and how to fix that kind of problem in the future? Thank you in advance.

I am using Lumix G6 with standard lens.

Answer (score 5):

You need better, fuller spectrum light. And you need more of it. The issues you have with your images are due to poor lighting, under exposure, and the resulting high noise.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here is too high iso, in combination with a maybe not optimal jpeg engine - all resulting in blotchy image noise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_noise
Read and understand thie following to expose better in the future, it will help you in video, too:
https://fstoppers.com/education/exposure-triangle-understanding-how-aperture-shutter-speed-and-iso-work-together-72878
In video you mostly don't see the noise that badly because your brain can filter it out in averaging over the frames. In still photography it is much more visible to the eye.

**To resolve your problem**: lower the ISO and in turn open the aperture or prolong your exposure to keep the image at the same brightness. If neither of those can be done due to circumstances, out-of-camera methods could involve adding light to the scene or changing lenses to a faster lens, if the limitation had been gear and not depth of field.

Comment: "To resolve your problem:" - and use RAW too.

Answer (score 1):

In your current condition, you have cranked your ISO too high.

Anything above 3200 ISO (dependent on camera, so can do well even on high ISO) will create noise and compromise the image, but given your current circumstance I am not sure if you can increase your exposure by decreasing the shutter speed or decreasing the f-stop.

If this is the case, your only option is to get more even lighting by bringing in more light or doing it at daytime.

**NOTE**: In a very well lit environment, even with artificial lighting, the light is normally much weaker than sunlight, and if you use your camera in Auto, they will automatically increase the ISO.